# python regex to get numbers placed in different position of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nlp

These are the possible cases of text I have,

```
4 bedrooms 2 bathrooms 3 carparks
3 bedroom house
Bedrooms 2, 
beds 5,
Bedrooms 1, 
2 bedrooms, 1 bathroom, 
Four bedrooms home, double garage
Four bedrooms home
Three double bedrooms home, garage
Three bedrooms home,
2 bedroom home unit with single carport.
Garage car spaces: 2, Bathrooms: 4, Bedrooms: 7,
```

I am trying to get the number of bedrooms out of this text. I managed to write the below ones,

```
  def get_bedroom_num(s):
    if ':' in s:
        out = re.search(r'(?:Bedrooms:|Bedroom:)(.*)', s,re.I).group(1)
    elif ',' in s:
        out = re.search(r'(?:bedrooms|bedroom|beds)(.*)', s,re.I).group(1)
    else:
        out = re.search(r'(.*)(?:bedrooms|bedroom).*', s,re.I).group(1)
    out = filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), out)
    return out
```

But it is not capturing all the possible cases. The key here is the word 'bedroom', text will always have the text bedroom either in the front or back of the number. Any better approach to handle this? If not through regex, may be Named Entity Recognition in NLP?

Thanks.

EDIT : -

For case 7 to 10, I managed to convert the word numbers to integer using the below function,

```
#Convert word to number
def text2int (textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
        units = [
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
        "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
        "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
        ]

        tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

        scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

        numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
        for idx, word in enumerate(units):  numwords[word] = (1, idx)
        for idx, word in enumerate(tens):       numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
        for idx, word in enumerate(scales): numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    ordinal_words = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fifth':5, 'eighth':8, 'ninth':9, 'twelfth':12}
    ordinal_endings = [('ieth', 'y'), ('th', '')]

    textnum = textnum.replace('-', ' ')

    current = result = 0
    curstring = ""
    onnumber = False
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word in ordinal_words:
            scale, increment = (1, ordinal_words[word])
            current = current * scale + increment
            if scale > 100:
                result += current
                current = 0
            onnumber = True
        else:
            for ending, replacement in ordinal_endings:
                if word.endswith(ending):
                    word = "%s%s" % (word[:-len(ending)], replacement)

            if word not in numwords:
                if onnumber:
                    curstring += repr(result + current) + " "
                curstring += word + " "
                result = current = 0
                onnumber = False
            else:
                scale, increment = numwords[word]

                current = current * scale + increment
                if scale > 100:
                    result += current
                    current = 0
                onnumber = True

    if onnumber:
        curstring += repr(result + current)

    return curstring
```

so, 'Four bedrooms home, double garage' can be converted to '4 bedrooms home, double garage' with this function before doing any regex to get the number.

Comment: I don't think that pure regex is the best option here.  Instead, I recommend writing a parser which processes each CSV term separately, and identifies the quantity and item.

Comment: **Expected Output** What is the Expected Output? I mean as you say, the number can occur on either side of some bedrooms. In addition, some "Bedrooms" are capitalized and it always seems to occur on the right of those. What is the expected output?

Comment: Just the number of bedroom. For first example, 4 is the expected output.

Comment: And should the "Three double" bedrooms be captured?

Comment: Not the double, just 3 in that should be captured.

Comment: '(one|two|Three|Four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)|\b[]*[0-9]{0,2}' use this type of regex to capture all the numbers

Comment: I tried this, s = "bedrooms 1,"
rgx = '(one|two|Three|Four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)|\b[]*[0-9]{0,2}'
m = re.search(rgx, s)
print m, but this returned None.

Comment: See if [this](https://regex101.com/r/DAzLMU/1) helps. Also, for capturing only numbers or number in word form you can use something like `\b(one|two|...|\d+)\b`

Comment: check with following link : https://regex101.com/r/fX2bZ8/429

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi when i change the programming language to python in the link you provided, it breaks. It is working only in PHP. :(

Comment: @MandarDhadve Yeah checked that link, it captures every number in the string, but i want only bedroom.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi   Awesome, this works. Can you add this as an answer. But, this results me '4 bedrooms',three bedrooms,bedrooms: 7, etc.. Is there a way to get only the number? If not, not a big issue, i can parse it.

Comment: Thanks all for your effort. It works.

Comment: I see. You wanted beds. Coolbeans.

Comment: Yes @FailSafe, Pushpesh solution worked for all my cases. It captured number of bedrooms in all cases. It also resulted text 'beds','bedroom',etc.. but that's ok.

Comment: @ds_user: I've added my solution as answer. Let me know if any of the cases you have goes uncovered anytime.

Comment: You can and probably should have a parser first pass that throws away words like *double, home, unit, with, ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following regex to find all different combinations and extract the bedroom number info,

```
(\w+\+?) *(?:double +)?bed(?:room)?s?|bed(?:room)?s?:? *(\d+\+?)
```

To precisely list only words form of number, you can change `(\w+)` to `\b(?:one|two|Three|Four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|\d+)\b`

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DAzLMU/4)**

Since the regex has alternation groups, where the captured information may be available in either group1 or group2, this Python code shows how you can extract the data from appropriately captured group in the regex,

```
import re

def getRoomInfo(s):
 numRooms = re.search(r'(\w+\+?) *(?:double +)?bed(?:room)?s?|bed(?:room)?s?:? *(\d+\+?)', s, re.IGNORECASE)
 if (numRooms):
  if (numRooms.group(1) is not None):
   return numRooms.group(1)
  elif (numRooms.group(2) is not None):
   return numRooms.group(2)


arr = ['4 bedrooms 2 bathrooms 3 carparks','3 bedroom house','Bedrooms 2, ','beds 5,','Bedrooms 1, ','2 bedrooms, 1 bathroom, ','Four bedrooms home, double garage','Four bedrooms home','Three double bedrooms home, garage','Three bedrooms home,','2 bedroom home unit with single carport.','Garage car spaces: 2, Bathrooms: 4, Bedrooms: 7,\\\\', 'Three bedroom bungalow with conservatory and", "One bedroom unit","4+ bedroom(s), 2 bathroom(s), 2 garage(s)']

for s in arr:
 print(s, ' --> ', getRoomInfo(s))
```

Prints following,

```
4 bedrooms 2 bathrooms 3 carparks  -->  4
3 bedroom house  -->  3
Bedrooms 2,   -->  2
beds 5,  -->  5
Bedrooms 1,   -->  1
2 bedrooms, 1 bathroom,   -->  2
Four bedrooms home, double garage  -->  Four
Four bedrooms home  -->  Four
Three double bedrooms home, garage  -->  Three
Three bedrooms home,  -->  Three
2 bedroom home unit with single carport.  -->  2
Garage car spaces: 2, Bathrooms: 4, Bedrooms: 7,\\  -->  7
Three bedroom bungalow with conservatory and", "One bedroom unit","4+ bedroom(s), 2 bathroom(s), 2 garage(s)  -->  Three
```

**Edit2: Another version of Python code where it captures all the matches in string and returns the result as a list**

```
import re

def getRoomInfoAll(s):
 matches = []
 pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+\+?) *(?:double +)?bed(?:room)?s?|bed(?:room)?s?:? *(\d+\+?)', re.IGNORECASE)
 for numRooms in pattern.finditer(s):
  if (numRooms.group(1) is not None and len(numRooms.group(1)) > 0):
   matches.append(numRooms.group(1))
  elif (numRooms.group(2) is not None and len(numRooms.group(2)) > 0):
   matches.append(numRooms.group(2))
 return matches


arr = ['4 bedrooms 2 bathrooms 3 carparks','3 bedroom house','Bedrooms 2, ','beds 5,','Bedrooms 1, ','2 bedrooms, 1 bathroom, ','Four bedrooms home, double garage','Four bedrooms home','Three double bedrooms home, garage','Three bedrooms home,','2 bedroom home unit with single carport.','Garage car spaces: 2, Bathrooms: 4, Bedrooms: 7,\\\\', 'Three bedroom bungalow with conservatory and", "One bedroom unit","4+ bedroom(s), 2 bathroom(s), 2 garage(s)']

for s in arr:
 print(s, ' --------> ', getRoomInfoAll(s))
```

Here it prints all the matches found in the string.

```
4 bedrooms 2 bathrooms 3 carparks  -------->  ['4']
3 bedroom house  -------->  ['3']
Bedrooms 2,   -------->  ['2']
beds 5,  -------->  ['5']
Bedrooms 1,   -------->  ['1']
2 bedrooms, 1 bathroom,   -------->  ['2']
Four bedrooms home, double garage  -------->  ['Four']
Four bedrooms home  -------->  ['Four']
Three double bedrooms home, garage  -------->  ['Three']
Three bedrooms home,  -------->  ['Three']
2 bedroom home unit with single carport.  -------->  ['2']
Garage car spaces: 2, Bathrooms: 4, Bedrooms: 7,\\  -------->  ['7']
Three bedroom bungalow with conservatory and", "One bedroom unit","4+ bedroom(s), 2 bathroom(s), 2 garage(s)  -------->  ['Three', 'One', '4+']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just noticed that it is not capturing these ones, - "Three bedroom bungalow with conservatory and", "One bedroom unit","4+ bedroom(s), 2 bathroom(s), 2 garage(s)" :(

Comment: @ds_user: I see it is capturing `Three` and `One` and not `4+`. Do you also want to capture `4+`? if yes, then optional `+` will have to be accounted in regex.

Comment: Yes even i see it is capturing in your link, but it is not in my data. Do you see anything wrong in this? `def get_num_bed(row):
    s = row['property_details'].strip()
    rgx = r'(\w+) *(?:double +)?bed(room)?s?|bed(?:room)?s?:? *(\d+)'
    m = re.search(rgx, s.lower())
    if m :
        return filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), m.group())`

Comment: Where do I have to add + in that regex?

Comment: Yes, let me account optional `+` in regex and give you a sample code for Python where it will extract the room number only.

Comment: @ds_user: I've added Python code, where I've written a function to return only the room info. You can see how I've extracted the info depending upon which alternation part matched in the regex. Also, for the last example, where there are multiple matches in the regex, we will have to change the code a bit to capture all room info and return as a list. Let me know if you want that too. It's simple change I can do for you.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your effort. Let me check this.

Comment: @ds_user: I've also added another version of Python code, which captures all matches in the string and returns them as a list. Hope this helps and let me know if you further face any issues.

Comment: Thank you. It is capturing everything. And it does not need to capture list, that is ok. I just found out the issue, regex is capturing everything fine. But I am trying to convert word numbers like 'one', 'two' to integer. Thats where something is happening and i am getting null values for those ones. Trying to fix that now.